# JQuery Mobile validation and AJAX POST form submission

Tags: jquery, ajax, validation, jquery-mobile, post

In the following code snippet, I am trying to build a login page using JQuery Mobile. I try to validate the inputs using JQuery validation blugin. If the validation went OK, I use AJAX to post the login data to a PHP code in the server.
This is what my code is supposed to do, however, all it does is redirecting me to the first page (language selection screen). Could you please help me to find out what is wrong with my code. Thank you

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
<head> 
   <meta charset="utf-8"> 
   <title></title> 
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css">
   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script> 
   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
   <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
   <script src="jquerytest.js"></script>
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head> 
<body>
 <!-- Select Language Screen -->
 <div data-role="page" data-theme="c" id="select_language_screen">
     <div data-role="header"> 
           <h1>Header</h1> 
     </div> 
     <div data-role="content">     
           <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-dividertheme="b" id="listview_language"> 
                 <li data-role="list-divider">Select a langauge</li>
                 <li data-name="en"><a href="#login_screen">English</a></li>
           </ul>            
     </div>   
    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
     <h4>Footer </h4>
    </div>
 </div>
 <!-- Login Screen -->
 <div data-role="page" id="login_screen" data-add-back-btn="true">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Header</h1>
    </div>

    <div data-role="content">
        <form id="login_form">
            <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                <label for="mobile_number" id="login_mobile_no_label">Mobile Number</label><br>
                <input type="text" name="mobile_number" id="login_mobile_no_input" class="required number"/><br><br>

                <label for="password" id="login_password_label">Password</label><br>
                <input type="password" name="password" id="login_password_input" class="required"  />
                <h3 id="notification"></h3>
                <button data-theme="b" id="submit" type="submit">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
        <h3>Footer</h3> 
    </div>
    <script>
        function onSuccess(data, status)
        {
            data = $.trim(data);
            $("#notification").text(data);
        }

        function onError(data, status)
        {
            $("#notification").text("Could not connect to the server!");
        }        

        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#submit").click(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                var validator = $(form_id).validate({
                    invalidHandler: function() {
                        if(validator.numberOfInvalids() <= 0)
                        {
                            var form = $("#login_form");
                            $("#submit",form).attr("disabled","disabled");
                            var formData = $("#login_form").serialize();
                            $.ajax({
                                type: "POST",
                                url: "login.php",
                                cache: false,
                                data: formData,
                                success: onSuccess,
                                error: onError
                            });
                            $("#submit").removeAttr("disabled");
                            return false;
                        }
                        else
                            alert("Please fill");
                    }
                }); 

            });
        });
    </script>
</div>
```

Comment: Maybe your form is submitted. Comment out your ajax call and see if preventdefault is sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

jQuery mobile doesn't work that way. You really need to read more about jQM. Basically none of your code is being executed and even when someone comes to this page from another page even less of it will be executed. 
First thing you need to know is your form is already ajax enabled , every form request is an ajax call unless it has the data-ajax='false' attribute, and every link is a ajax request unless it is external, has rel="external", data-ajax='true' or a target attribute.

Second thing you should know is that jQM removed most of your code and your entire $(document).ready block of code is not going to work, since it is removed as soon as jQM rebuilds the DOM... how this exactly works I am not sure. I came across your question looking for answers myself, I am pretty new and doing my first jQM project and after I love it for what I am using it for, If you need alot of other jquery plugins and custom scripts jQM is probably not the right solution for you.

So this is what you should do, you should write your form as if it was to work without javascript, then add a `required` attribute to both inputs and a `pattern= “[0-9]”`or simply  `type="number"`  to phone number, HTML5 browsers which is what you are dealing with on smart phones as they don't have IE and etc :D automatically will validate and even output a nice error.

See http://www.pageresource.com/html5/input-validation-tutorial/ for more validation rules.